# C - Why does my code break when removing unused variable declaration

Tags: c, fwrite, cs50

I am writing a program in C to recover images from a raw file for CS50 and I am having a strange problem. I have a variable int cnt that I was using for debug purposes and I got the program to work so I was removing leftover debug code. But when I remove the cnt declaration I start outputting corrupt files.
Before removing line 25 below I was outputing .jpg files that I could open and view, then I removed the line, recompiled, deleted the photos from the last run, and reran the program on the same .raw data and the new files I got were unrecognized. So I put the declaration back in, recompiled, deleted the old photos, and ran the program again and got good files. Does anyone know why removing an unused declaration is messing with my results? The offending declaration is on line 25.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdint.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      if (argc != 2)
      {
          printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
         return 1;
     }

     int filesFound = 0;

     FILE *inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
     FILE *outFile = NULL;

     if (inFile == NULL)
     {
         printf("Image file could not be opened\n");
         return 1;
     }

     uint8_t buffer[512];
     int cnt = 0;

     while (!feof(inFile))
     {
         fread(buffer, 512, 1, inFile);

         // check for start of jpg file
         if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
         {
             // start of jpg was found
             if (outFile != NULL)
             {
                 // close the current file and then open a new file to write to
                 fclose(outFile);
                 outFile = NULL;
             }

             // open a file to write to
            char fName[4];
             sprintf(fName, "%03i.jpg", filesFound);
             outFile = fopen(fName, "w");

             filesFound++;
         }

         if (outFile != NULL){
             // we have found data to write and opened a file
             fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, outFile);
         }
     }

     //Be sure to close my files
     fclose(inFile);

     if (outFile != NULL)
     {
         fclose(outFile);
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please don't include line numbers. It makes it impossible to copy paste your code and compile. Use comments to indicate the lines instead.

Comment: `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong

Comment: `char fName[4]` does not have sufficient room for the name generated by `%03i.jpg`, so you are overrunning the buffer. Use `snprintf`, not `sprintf`, and test the return value to detect errors.

Comment: `fname` is too small.

Comment: creating a 4-character string with this: `sprintf(fName, "%03i.jpg", filesFound);`. Seriously?

Comment: In other words: `char fName[4];` -> `char fName[100];`

Comment: ideally `char fName[PATH_MAX];`

Comment: `"Image file could not be opened\n"` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Use: `if( (inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL ) { perror( argv[1]); ...}`

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Increasing the size of fName worked. That was driving me nuts. So this must have been overflowing into my buffer value then, is that right?

Comment: I just realised that I was adding .jpg to the string as well as the numbers and this is why I was having trouble. In an earlier version, I was just using "%03i" (no .jpg at the end) and I wasn't paying enough attention when I changed it and needed a bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

char `fName[4]` does not have sufficient room for the name generated by `"%03i.jpg"`, so you are overrunning the buffer. Make it larger and use `snprintf`, not `sprintf`, and test the return value to detect errors:

```
int result = snprintf(fName, sizeof fName, "%03i.jpg", filesFound);
if (sizeof fName <= result)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Internal error, buffer is too small for file name.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Instead of printing an error, you could instead use the return value of `snprintf`, which indicates the length needed, to allocate memory for a larger buffer and then redo the `snprintf` with that buffer.

(Note that `snprintf` may return a negative result if an error occurs. Normally, this will become a large number upon conversion to `size_t` for the comparison, so it will trigger this error message. However, in a robust program, you might want to insert a separate test for `result < 0`.)

Comment: Cool, thank you for the explanation. I have used some higher level languages but this is my first time using C so I'm not used to having worry about things like having a large enough space to store a string.